# jq filter items where values in a nested array array are different

Tags: jq

Let's say I have the following json. I want to get all the items where the "employee" had different teams over the year.

```
[
    {
        "id": 122343,
        "name": "Tom Muller",
        "teams": [
            {
                "year": "2010-2011",
                "team_id": 27
            },
            {
                "year": "2011-2012",
                "team_id": 27
            },
            {
                "year": "2013-2014",
                "team_id": 27
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 338744,
        "name": "Eric Gonzales",
        "teams": [
            {
                "year": "2010-2011",
                "team_id": 12
            },
            {
                "year": "2011-2012",
                "team_id": 17
            },
            {
                "year": "2013-2014",
                "team_id": 17
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like to query the array with jq and the output would return

```
{
        "id": 338744,
        "name": "Eric Gonzales",
        "teams": [
            {
                "year": "2010-2011",
                "team_id": 12
            },
            {
                "year": "2011-2012",
                "team_id": 17
            },
            {
                "year": "2013-2014",
                "team_id": 17
            }
        ]
    }
```

How would I write such a query ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `unique_by` you can reduce the `.teams` array to those that differ in their `.team_id`, and with `select` and `length` you can filter for those that have strictly more than just one such item.

```sh
jq '.[] | select(.teams | unique_by(.team_id) | length > 1)'
```

```json
{
  "id": 338744,
  "name": "Eric Gonzales",
  "teams": [
    {
      "year": "2010-2011",
      "team_id": 12
    },
    {
      "year": "2011-2012",
      "team_id": 17
    },
    {
      "year": "2013-2014",
      "team_id": 17
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/eM5y829IQp)

This gives you a stream of objects (in case there's more than one result). Use `map(select(…))` instead of `.[] | select(…)` if you want to have them as an array.